# How to snap to geometry for the measure tool

Tags: 3d-view, snapping, measurement

Is there some way that I could make the measure tool to snap to points on an object to get more accurate measurement. Like if I'm trying to measure the distance between two object, is there some kind of way that the measure tool snaps to edges of the two objects. I've been using Fusion360 for a while and in there there are snap settings to snap onto different kind of geometry.

Is there something like that in Blender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl enables snapping.  Drag out a measurement line, then hover over one end so you can pick it up.  Holding Ctrl, drag it over to your object.  Repeat for the other end of the measurement.

Hint, you can measure angles in a similar fashion by grabbing the middle of the measurement line.

"X" deletes the measurement.

Comment: The fact that you can't snap to objects right when creating the measure tape (you have to create it, THEN place/snap its ends) is so blender.